# Can't Use nested scrolling gridview when using swipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, gridview

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:verticalSpacing="35dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:outlineProvider="background"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Now when scroll down the grid and up again the page refreshes instead of scrolling grid.
I only want the scroll to work when the grid is on its top position and then i pull down.
Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable=false;
        if(gridView!=null && gridView.getChildCount()>0){
            boolean firstItemVisible=(gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()==0);
            boolean topOfFirstItemVisible=(gridView.getChildAt(0).getTop()==0);
            enable=firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
    }
});
```

This code accomplishes what i wanted to do